# Alter character field to date

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting, date

I've a legacy postgres db that has date columns cast as `character(50)` fields (don't ask). I'd like to alter the table and columns to contain actual dates. Because this worked:

```
select distinct to_date(date_begin, 'YYYY DD MM') from dates;
```

I naively thought this might work:

```
alter table dates alter column date_begin type character
using to_date(date_begin, 'YYYY DD MM');
```

But it does not. Any clues for the clueless?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to add a new date column, migrate the data from the old column to the new column, verify the data is correct, drop the old column, and rename the new column to the old name?

Comment: @JimH. This may be the way to go in other RDBMS. You also have to take care of indexes, foreign keys, views etc. depending on the column. However, in PostgreSQL it *just works* as intended by the OP. See my answer for more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This **just works** as intended by the OP. What we have here is a simple thinko/typo.
Read more in the [manual about ALTER TABLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-altertable.html).
Demo:

```
-- DROP SCHEMA x CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA x;
CREATE TABLE x.tbl(date_begin character(50));
INSERT INTO x.tbl VALUES ('2011-11-11 11:11'), (NULL), (''), ('1977');
-- NULL and empty string work too
-- even just YYYY works: '1977' .. is converted to '1977-01-01' automatically
-- empty string produce a possibly surprising result: '0001-01-01 BC'

ALTER TABLE x.tbl ALTER COLUMN date_begin TYPE date USING to_date(date_begin, 'YYYY DD MM');

SELECT * FROM x.tbl;
```

Hint: You wrote `type character` instead of `type date`.

Comment: thinko/typo indeed. Thanks. I tried your experiment and it worked fine; however, trying it on my table public.dates I get nothing. I own the table and can `create` tables but doing this at the psql prompt: `ALTER TABLE dates ALTER COLUMN date_begin TYPE date USING to_date(date_begin, 'YYYY DD MM');` fails silently. What am I doing wrong? (note: there are a lot of null values in date_begin. Is that a problem?)

Comment: @jjon: NULL values are certainly not a problem. I amended my demo to include a NULL value, which works just as well. Not even empty strings would make this fail (while produce surprising dates).

Comment: @jjon: If it still doesn't seem to work, I wonder if you maight be mixing up table names or schemas? Look here for help on diagnosing that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8039116/adding-a-user-accounts-table-to-postgres-in-django-view/8074877#8074877

Comment: I see. Thank you. I think the problem must be this: a lot of 'dates' in date_begin are just YYYY instead of YYYY DD MM. Can to_date accept more than one kind of string formatting parameter?

Comment: @jjon: nah, that works, too. I amended my demo once more. If that works, as you posted: `select to_date(date_begin, 'YYYY DD MM') from dates;` then the `ALTER TABLE` command **works, too**. (`distinct` is irrelevant). Do you have a very old version of PostgreSQL by chance?

Comment: yes I see. I'm quite baffled. Postgres 9.0.3. And yes I see that the select query converts YYYY automatically so the alter table command should work too. argh! Thanks for trying. Your answer and comments have been instructive.

Comment: I restored from the original dump into a new db and found that this procedure for recasting the date field does indeed "just work". The old db would allow me to create and modify new tables, but I could not modify the old ones. I still have no idea why. Anyhow thanks @erwin for your help

Answer (score 0):

It will take three stages:

1) Alter the table to add the date column.

2) Run an update query which converts each string date into the date field

3) Alter the table to remove the text date column.