# Extract year from date within WHERE clause

Tags: postgresql, date, types, where-clause

I need to include `EXTRACT()` function within `WHERE` clause as follow:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) = '2014';
```

I get a message like this:

> ```
> pg_catalog.date_part(unknown, text) doesn't exist** 
> SQL State 42883
> ```

Here is `my_table` content (`gid INTEGER, date DATE`):

```
  gid  |    date
-------+-------------
  1    | 2014-12-12
  2    | 2014-12-08
  3    | 2013-17-15
```

I have to do it this way because the query is sent from a form on a website that includes a 'Year' field where users enter the year on a 4-digits basis.

Comment: So what's the question? Is it not working as you expected? Does this produce an error message?

Comment: I updated the message. There is indeed an error message...

Comment: This query works fine on my machine. What version of postgres are you using?

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.2.2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 32-bit

Comment: `extract` definitely existed in 9.2.2. Weird. Just for the fun of it, could you try with `date_part('year', date) = '2014'` instead of the `extract` expression you're currently using?

Comment: Your solution doesn't work. I solved it by forcing the type of DATE column : `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date::TIMESTAMP) = '2014';`. Thanks for help!

Comment: A normal index on field "date" doesn't help performance. Use the same EXTRACT() definition to create a functional index or use a BETWEEN-condition in your WHERE instead of the EXTRACT-condition.

Comment: Note: `date` is a word used in the sql syntax. I don't know if it is a reserved word, but you should avoid using it as an identifier.

Answer (score 15):

Your column is of **data type** [`text`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html), while [`EXTRACT()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) only works for [`date` / `time` types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html).

You should convert your column to the appropriate data type.

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN date TYPE date;
```

That's just 4 bytes instead of 11 for the text, faster and cleaner (disallows illegal dates and most typos).
If you have non-standard format add a `USING` clause with a conversion  expression. Example:

- [Alter character field to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099352/Alter-character-field-to-date/8099692#8099692)

For your queries to be **fast with a plain index** on `date` you should use [sargable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sargable) predicates. Like:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE    date >= '2014-01-01'
AND      date <  '2015-01-01';
```

Or, to go with your 4-digit input for the year:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE    date >= to_date('2014', 'YYYY')
AND      date <  to_date('2015', 'YYYY');
```

You could also be more explicit:

```
to_date('2014' || '0101', 'YYYYMMDD')
```

Either produces the same date `'2014-01-01'`.

Aside: `date` is a [reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in standard SQL and a basic type name in Postgres. Don't use it as identifier.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because the column has a text or varchar type, as opposed to `date` or `timestamp`. This is easily reproducible:

```
SELECT 1 WHERE extract(year from '2014-01-01'::text)='2014';
```

yields this error:

> ERROR:  function pg_catalog.date_part(unknown, text) does not exist
>   LINE 1: SELECT 1 WHERE extract(year from '2014-01-01'::text)='2014';
>                          ^ HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

`extract` or is underlying function `date_part` does not exist for text-like datatypes, but they're not needed anyway. Extracting the year from this date format is equivalent to getting the 4 first characters, so your query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE left(date,4)='2014';
```